# add control to resource routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

My resource route looks like :

```
$router->resource('subnets', 'subnetController');
```

I saw on the documentation that a resource route can have an array of parameters... is there a parameter that permits you to choose who can access to those routes ? If I was using basic routing that would be something like :

```
Route::get('/subnets', function () {
   if (Auth::user()['attributes']['role'] == 'admin') return view('subnets.index');
   else return view ('errors.403');
});
```

Comment: You should look the middlewares implementatio: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

Comment: as the pervious comment mentions, you can make a middleware to do that check and can define it in the controller or via the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use middleware..

1. create middleware > https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware
2. write this on handler middleware

> ```
> public function handle($request, Closure $next)
>     {
>         if ($request->user()->role == 'admin') {
>              return $next($request);
>          }
>          abort(403, 'Access denied');
>     }
> ```

3. routes.php

> ```
>   Route::group(['middleware' => 'your_middleware_name'], function () {
>       Route::resource('subnets', 'subnetController');
>      });
> ```

Comment: `Route::group()` is what i was missing..Thanks !